# Pseudo Code - Position Finder

Tags: python, pseudocode

I am a complete novice to python and am trying to attempt pseudo code, I know pseudo code isnt a language, as shown in other questions but I cannot grasp how to simplify down code to make it work, especially after I spent a lot of time on this code.

So if possible, could somebody show me how I would pseudo code this code as I am extremely confused :), thanks in advance.

Comment: why would someone vote to close this :) He wants pseudo-code as it is a tag !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo code is really up to the person. I typically don't pseudo code much unless trying to whiteboard something.

```
Setup alphabet
Find a valid character/word
    Get input and test each character/word to see if valid
Check if word is in the sentence
    Give the position
```